# Как сделать whitelist URLов в конфиге nginx?

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, rewrite, whitelist

Всем привет. суть вопроса в том что нужно прописать некую проверку есть ли такой URL и если его нет то выдавать 404.
кусок конфиг файла то что я пробывал сделать:

```
server
{
    listen localhost:80;
    server_name example.com;
    charset utf-8;
     location  / {
           root /var/www/html/;
           try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;   \\редирект всех запросов на index.html
            index index.html;
                 location ~* !^(\/|css|balance|deposit|signup|profilelogin|settings|static|fonts|img|index\.html|favicon\.ico)/
              {
               return 404;
               break;
            }
      }
}
```

раньше работало все это через htaccess:

```
 RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html
####404 rules

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/signup
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/market
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/support
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/profie
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/login
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/settings
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/static.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/fonts.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/img.*

RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
```

Сейчас пробую сделать вот так, но теперь любой запрос кидает на 404(( хорошо сервак тестовый.

```
server
{
    listen localhost:80;

    charset utf-8;

root /var/www/html/;
index index.html;

location = / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}

location = (css|market|deposit|signup|support|login|settings|static|fonts|img) {
index /index.html;
}

location =/favicon.ico{
index /favicon.ico;
}

location  / {
   return 404;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
location / {
    return 404;
}

location ~ ^/(signup|market|support|profie|login|settings|index\.html|static|fonts|img|$) {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

Comment: не помогло к сожалению. просто перманентная 404. (

Comment: Отредактировал, еще раз попробуйте.